# Unable to call django view using ajax

Tags: python, django, ajax

I want to call the django view from client side that will display all the messages from the models on the html page

AJAX function

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : "/load_with_room_name/{{room_name}}/",
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                $("#display").empty();
            },
            error: function(response){
                alert('An error occured')
            }
        });
    },1000);
    })
    </script>
```

django view function

```
def load_with_room_name(request,room_name):
    try:
        current_user = Account.objects.get(email=str(request.user))
        chat_room = ChatRoom.objects.get(room_name=room_name)
        if chat_room.room_user_1 == current_user or chat_room.room_user_2 == current_user:
            print(current_user)
            return redirect('room',room_name,current_user.username)
        else:
            return redirect('chat')
    except Exception as e:
        log_exception(request,e,view_name="load_with_room_name")
        return render(request,"error.html")
```

django urlpattern for the above view

```
 urlpatterns = [    path('load_with_room_name/<str:room_name>',views.load_with_room_name,name='load_with_room_name'),
    ]
```

Comment: please add the error details.

Answer (score 0):

change url to

```
 url : "{% url 'load_with_room_name' room_name %}",
```

in order to use the django url-pattern and be aware of the trailing slash in your original code. There is no trailing slash in your url-pattern!

Answer (score 0):

while you have already tested that it works by accessing it correctly in your django project only I see that you would only need to add the full path as follows

```
 url : window.location.origin + "/load_with_room_name/{{room_name}}/",
```